# Parameters being passed into Web SQL callback are undefined

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I have an Web SQL insert query within 3 loops that are using 3 variables - one loop uses l, the second uses k, the third uses i.

I'm trying to use l, k, and i in the callback for the insert query, but they're coming up as undefined when I console log them out.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

```html
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO items (parameter1, parameter2)' + ' VALUES(?,?);',[1,2], 
 function(tx, results,l,k,i){
  console.log("l =", l)
  console.log("k =", k)
  console.log("i =", i)
 }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your question correctly, the variables `l`, `k` and `i` are already defined outside the scope of the callback function.

If you try to add them as parameters to the callback function, as you do in your code example, you are actually creating new variables of the same name. This is sometimes called “shadowing”. Since the callback only gets two arguments assigned to those parameters (`tx` and `result`), the other parameter `l`, `k` and `i` are simply `undefined`.

All you need to do to fix your code is remove the parameters `l`, `k` and `i` from the callback to avoid the shadowing:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO items (parameter1, parameter2)' + ' VALUES(?,?);',[1,2], 
    function(tx, results){
        console.log("l =", l)
        console.log("k =", k)
        console.log("i =", i)
    }
);
```

The callback function is executed at the window level, so your variables will also need to be declared at the window level.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are having problems with l, k and i getting undefined or replaced because the callback is taking longer than expected. (at least, my case was like that).

You can create a function as a callback that receives all the parameters, and then use bind() to pass is as the callback.

This is an example for your case :

```
   function cb(l,k,i,tx,results)
   {
     console.log("l =", l)
     console.log("k =", k)
     console.log("i =", i)
   }

   xcb = cb.bind(null,"one","two","three");
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO items (parameter1, parameter2)' + ' VALUES(?,?);',[1,2], xcb, null );
```

At the line using bind( , you can pass the variables or values for l,k,i.